# How to config Oracle RAC in spring boot application.properties

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.5.0.release and I want to connect my application to oracle database using oracle RAC (Fast Connection Failover) and the jdbc string like this :

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:oracle:thin:jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac1-vip-ent.mncplaymedia.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac2-vip-ent.mncplaymedia.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac3-vip-ent.mncplaymedia.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac4-vip-ent.mncplaymedia.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac5-vip-ent.mncplaymedia.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ent)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES = 180)(DELAY = 5))))

spring.datasource.username:xxxx
spring.datasource.password:xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

and I got error Datasource return null like this :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: DataSource returned null unexpectedly
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:343) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:na]
... 71 common frames omitted
```

any one get this problem before, please help me to resolve this. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out the [UCP with Spring](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ucp-with-spring-framework) blog ?